# How to implement the same picker view for time edit screen as in freshbooks?

Tags: ios, custom-controls, uipickerview

I need to implement the same time edit screen as in freshbooks application.
I cannot use date picker and I need only hours and minutes with proper digits.
Is there any ready-made control/class for this task?

Here is an image of what I need exaclty (without seconds).
http://s018.radikal.ru/i513/1409/32/804224a9b2a6.png

Comment: Why can't you use date picker ? It 100% fits to your problem.